# I want to know why there is a Spread Operator in the providers section

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Here is my code.

database.providers.ts

```js
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
    useFactory: async () => await createConnection({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [
          __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
      ],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  },
];
```

database.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { databaseProviders } from './database.providers';

@Module({
  providers: [...databaseProviders],
  exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

What kinds of erros can exist when I use just [databaseProviders] in database.module.ts?

Comment: `[databaseProviders]` makes an array containing a single item, which is the other array (i.e., the structure ends up as `[[{...}]]` -- note those are two sets of brackets). `[...databaseProviders]` copies the contents into another array (structure becomes `[{...}]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`databaseProviders` is already an array, of a single element, but still an array. `providers` and `exports` expects to get an array of providers (custom, or otherwise), so if you were to do `providers: databaseProviders` or `providers: [ ...databaseProviders ]` you're good, because these are both arrays of single depth. However, if you do `providers: [databaseProviders]` this is a two dimensional array, or an array of arrays, which Nest does not handle, so you need to use that `spread` operator (the `...`) to turn the array from `databaseProviders` into individual elements for the `providers` and `exports` arrays